# Evaluating the products $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[n/4]} \tan \dfrac{k\pi}{n}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reseaching a problem that lead me to evaluating the product
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{[n/4]} \tan \dfrac{k\pi}{n}=?,$$
I can evaluate
$$\prod\limits_{k=1, k\neq \frac{n}{2}}^{n}\vert \tan \dfrac{k\pi}{n}\vert=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}n, n \text{ is odd} \\
1, n\text{ is even} \end{array}\right.,$$
but i can't solve the above product, please. Thanks a ton.

Comment: What do you get for the first few cases?

Comment: The product looks very ugly :-/ when opened!

Comment: I tried the first few cases, the product is irrational numbers but i wanna try to write the result neatly and exactly so as run with low condition number in matlab :(